# Can't quite get the randomization down

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, random

I have built a specialized card application.  What it does is allow a user to 'draw' a card, then view the card, and place it back in a random place in the deck.  The only problem that I am having is that, more often than not, the card is being placed at the top of the deck.

Here is the contents of the .h file:

```
@class _Card;

@interface _Deck : NSObject

@property (readonly) NSString *deckData;
@property (readonly) NSUInteger count;
@property (readonly) NSUInteger deckCount;
@property (readonly) BOOL needsReset;
@property (readonly) NSArray *cards;

- (id)initWithArray:(NSArray *)array;
- (id)initWithContentsOfFile:(NSString *)filePath;

- (void)shuffle;
- (NSArray *)draw;
- (void)reset;
- (void)changeEdition;

@end
```

Now, here is my draw method, which will draw a card (more than one if the cards so specify it) and then place that card back into the deck, if it is allowed:

```
- (NSArray *)draw {

    // first, we create an array that can be returned, populated with the
    // cards that we drew
    NSMutableArray *drawArray = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];

    // next, we get the top card, which is actually located in the 
    // indexArray (I use this for shuffling, pulling cards, etc.)
    NSNumber *index = [[[indexArray objectAtIndex:0] retain] autorelease];

    // now we get the card that the index corresponds to
    // from the cards array
    _Card *card = [cards objectAtIndex:[index integerValue]];

    // now I remove the index that we 
    // got from the indexArray...don't worry,
    // it might be put back in
    [indexArray removeObject:index];

    // if the card is supposed to discard after
    // draw, we leave it out
    if(!card.discard) {

        int insertIndex = arc4random_uniform(indexArray.count);

        // then I insert the card into the deck using the random, random 
        // number
        [indexArray insertObject:index atIndex:insertIndex];
    }

    _Card *cardCopy = [card copy];

    // we add the card to the array 
    // that we will return
    [drawArray addObject:cardCopy];

    // next, if the card is not the final card...
    if(!card.final) {

        // ...and the card has an 
        // additional draw specified...
        if(card.force) {

            // we keep drawing until we need to stop
            [drawArray addObjectsFromArray:[self draw]];
        }
    }

    return drawArray;
}
```

Is there anything that I may be doing wrong? If you need any more information, please let me know.  Thanks in advance for any help that you can provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am understanding this correctly, the problem is that it is inserting the card at index 0 in indexArray?

Okay, have you tried something like this:

(don't use this line yet `[indexArray removeObject:index];`)

```
if(!card.discard)
{
    int insertIndex = arc4random_uniform(indexArray.count);
    id obj = [indexArray objectAtIndex:index];
    [indexArray removeObjectAtIndex:index];
    [indexArray insertObject:obj atIndex:insertIndex];
NSLog(@"insertIndex is %i and obj is %@", insertIndex, obj);
}
else
{
    [indexArray removeObjectAtIndex:index];
}
```

Your code seems to be okay, I'm guessing it just doesn't like removing the object before... I added the log just so you could see if it really was inserting it at the top each time. Give me an update- if this doesn't work, I could take a look at your project file.

Comment: Well, what I am doing is I have two `NSMutableArray` objects.  the first one (cards) holds all of the _Card objects in the order that they are specified in a plist file.  The second (indexArray) holds a set of `NSNumber` objects that represent the card 'index' numbers.  I randomize the `indexArray` array using the Fisher-Yates algorithm.  I then pull the topmost `index` (simulating the pulling of the top card).  Then I try to randomly place that index back in the `indexArray`.  Hope this helps to understand the problem

Comment: I did this, and what was suggested for testing, and it now seems to be giving a very good randomization of the cards.  Still pulling the same cards over and over, but in a more acceptable fashion.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What does "more often than not" mean?

What you show here looks perfect....

Remember that this is **random** and it is quite possible (although rare) to get a particular number 10 times in a row.  **Over the long run** you should get an even distribution though.

Run this routine 10,000,000 times or so, and check the number of times that you get each number (make sure that you have the same number of cards in the deck each time) before deciding that something is wrong.

Also, are you sure that your indexArray contains the correct values and you aren't duplicating 0 in there?

Comment: I will try running the routine over a long period like that.  The duplication of the index did cross my mind and I did make sure that I am not.  Thanks

Comment: Another good question would be "is `indexArray` definitely a real object with contents, i.e., is `indexArray.count` not returning 0 all the time?"

Comment: Ok, I tried calculating the random numbers over an iteration of 10,000,000 (wow did that take longer than I expected, lol).  After looking at the log (which took a long time too...) I did see that it's a very random list of numbers between the 0 and the total number of indexes.  Also, just for clarification, I create the indexArray array at the same time that I create the cards array, so they are both returning the same number of objects (unless a card is discarded)  Thanks.